# How do I increase a id value by 1 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, numbers

I can't get the value 0 to increase whenever I get a specific string for example I get a string of H and that should increment this id="number" by 1. This is a simple Heads or tails program I am learning to write.

```js
var coin = ['H', 'T']

function randomFlip() {
  var randomFlip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (coin.length));
  document.getElementById('hort').innerHTML = coin[randomFlip];

}
```

```html
<div class="number">0</div>

<div id="hort" style="text-align: center;">null</div>

<button onclick="randomFlip()" onclick="increase()">Flip the coin.</button>
```

Comment: Nothing here has an id of `number`.

Comment: You can't have two `onclick()` attributes. If you want to call two functions, put them in one: `onclick="randomFlip(); increase();"`

Comment: I just replaced the class with id. thanks.

Comment: <button onclick="randomFlip(); increase();">Flip the coin.</button> made some changes

Comment: @programmers Where is your `increase()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`increase()` can check the value of the `innerHTML` to see if it's `H`, and then increment the number.

```js
var coin = ['H', 'T']

function randomFlip() {
  var randomFlip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (coin.length));
  document.getElementById('hort').innerHTML = coin[randomFlip];
}

function increase() {
  var flip = document.getElementById('hort').innerHTML;
  if (flip == 'H') {
    document.querySelector(".number").innerText++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="number">0</div>

<div id="hort" style="text-align: center;">null</div>

<button onclick="randomFlip();increase()">Flip the coin.</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the count in a variable, then increment it and update the value in the element.

`var count = 0`

```
function randomFlip() {
  var randomFlip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (coin.length));
  document.getElementById('hort').innerHTML = coin[randomFlip];
  count = count + 1;
  document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].innerHTML = count;
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list, not a single element, you need `[0]`.

Comment: Based on the question, the counter should only increase if the flip comes up heads.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
    <div class="number" id='flips'>0</div>
    
    <div id="hort" style="text-align: center;">null</div>
    <script>
        var coin = ['H', 'T'];
        flips = 0;
    
    
    
        function randomFlip() {
            var randomFlip = Math.floor(Math.random() * (coin.length));
            document.getElementById('hort').innerHTML = coin[randomFlip];
            if(!randomFlip){
            flips++;
            document.getElementById('flips').innerHTML = flips;
            }
    
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="randomFlip()">Flip the coin.</button>
```